# Кто-нибудь знаком с gulp? (npm)

Tags: npm

Кто-нибудь знаком с gulp? 
устанавливаю через кс: npm I (node js и gulp - глобально уже установлены)
за пускаю gulp / выводит ошибку, кто-нибудь знает что нужно делать при такой ошибке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте от имени администратора запустить cmd и повторить всё то же самое

Comment: нужно удалять папку node_modules ,что бы заново переустановить ?

Comment: Тоже самое 

stream.js:74
throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
и пишет путь к stailschit.css

Comment: А может, ошибка в коде в gulpfile.js? Ему явно не нравится таск компиляции stylesheet.css